# Program terminates during run time

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures

Following is the code to multiply two matrices. It stops at the run time when I try to enter the elements of array. I have created different functions for tasks which were repeated so that it becomes modular and easy to understand and debug.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void input(int *rows, int *columns);                //Inputs rows and columns
void allocate(int **arr, int rows, int columns);    //Allocates memory for the array
void initialize(int **arr, int rows, int columns);  //Initializes(rather, declares because calloc initializes to zero) the array 
void release(int **arr, int rows);                  //Frees the dynamically allocated memory
int main(void)
{
    int **matrix1, **matrix2, **product, rows1, rows2, columns1, columns2, i, j;
    
    printf("\nEnter rows and columns of first matrix\n");
    input(&rows1, &columns1);
    allocate(matrix1, rows1, columns1);
    
    printf("\nEnter rows and columns of second matrix\n");
    input(&rows2, &columns2);
    allocate(matrix2, rows2, columns2);
    
    if(columns1 != rows2)
    {
        printf("Matrix cannot be multiplied!");
        exit(0);
    }
    
    printf("\nEnter the contents of matrix 1\n");
```

This line is where the problem begins:

```
initialize(matrix1, rows1, columns1);
```

The rest of the program is as follows:

```
    printf("\nEnter the contents of matrix 2\n");
    initialize(matrix2, rows2, columns2);
        
    initialize(product, rows1, columns2);
    for(i = 0; i < rows1; i++)
        for(j = 0; j < columns2; j++)
            for(int k = 0; k < columns1; k++)
                product[i][j] = product[i][j] + matrix1[i][k] * matrix2[k][j];
            
    for(i = 0; i < rows1; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < columns2; j++)
            printf("%d ", product[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
        
    release(matrix1, rows1);
    release(matrix2, rows2);
    release(product, rows1);
}
```

input() gets the rows and columns for the array

```
void input(int *rows, int *columns)
{
    printf("Rows = ");
    scanf("%d", rows);
    printf("Columns = ");
    scanf("%d", columns);
}
```

The allocate() function dynamically allocates memory to matrices. First it allocates memory for **int*** type and then **int** type. It also checks for whether the memory is properly allocated or not by comparing it with NULL.

```
void allocate(int **arr, int rows, int columns)
{
    arr = (int**)calloc(rows, sizeof(int*));

    if(arr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Memory Allocation Failed!");
        exit(1);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = (int*)calloc(columns, sizeof(int));

        if(arr[i] == NULL)
        {
            printf("Memory Allocation Failed!");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

The initialize() function inputs the elements of array. The program works fine until it reaches this function. When I input the elements of array and hit enter, the program terminates and a dialog box appears which says:

> A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and notify if a solution is available.

```
void initialize(int **arr, int rows, int columns)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
            scanf("%d", &arr[i][j]);
}
```

The release() function releases the dynamically allocated memory.

```
void release(int **arr, int rows)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        free(arr[i]);
    free(arr);
}
```

Comment: Off the top of my head, I think it should be `scanf("%d", arr[i][j]);` in `initialize` function (notice the missing ampersand (`&`)).

Comment: Rahul Bharadwaj I agree these problems occur due missing ampersand in scanf() but in this case I have put the ampersand and still getting run time error

Comment: Honestly I suggest adding an interface description to all functions, for your own understanding. Doing this you will find that the design of `void allocate(int **arr, int rows, int columns)` is wrong. You want to get a pointer to `int*` as a result. First error: you didn't use the return value as result, this makes it harder to use the function. Second error: Since the behavior is not clearly documented, your missed that the argument `arr` is overwritten in the first line. Your intention might be to save the return value of `calloc` to `*arr`. -- Use: `int* allocate(int rows, int columns)`

Comment: harper I didn't get your point. I would be grateful If you elaborate a bit more. Second thing is that why can't I use the function allocate as it is? It should work since during the function call I am sending the address of matrix1 to arr1 and then allocating the memory. So it should be reflected in the original variable, i.e, matrix too

Comment: `(int**)calloc(rows, sizeof(int*));` There is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not initializing those pointers with your `allocate` function, then you're segfaulting on uninitialized memory.

To make your code work with minimal changes you could use three star pointers instead:

```
void allocate(int ***arr, int rows, int columns)
{
    *arr = (int**)calloc(rows, sizeof(int*));
    if(*arr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Memory Allocation Failed!");
        exit(1);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        (*arr)[i] = (int*)calloc(columns, sizeof(int));
        if((*arr)[i] == NULL)
        {
            printf("Memory Allocation Failed!");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

And then change each call to the `allocate` function body appropriately

```
allocate(&matrix1, &rows1, columns1);
```

But that gets difficult to reason about. A more correct answer is to recompose the `allocate` function to *return* the desired arrays instead:

```
int ** allocate(int rows, int columns)
{
    int **arr = calloc(rows, sizeof(int*));
    if(arr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Memory Allocation Failed!");
        exit(1);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = (int*)calloc(columns, sizeof(int));
        if(arr[i] == NULL)
        {
            printf("Memory Allocation Failed!");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Calls to allocate now look like this:

```
matrix1 = allocate(rows1, columns1);
```

Bonus Bug:

You're not calling `allocate` for the `products` array at all, which will also (often) cause a segfault.

Comment: But ```int ***arr; *arr = (int**)calloc(rows, sizeof(int*));``` and ```int **arr; arr = (int**)calloc(rows, sizeof(int*));``` are same in their effect

Comment: No they are not. The first writes through a pointer to a `int **` provided from `main`. The second writes to a _copy_ of `int **` provided by main.

Do you see the difference? In your version of `allocate` you are just copying the `int **` from `main`. The `int **`s _in_ `main` never change.

Comment: Better choice: is changing the type to `int **` and returning a pointer to the allocated block of pointers. Always avoid becoming a *Three-Star* programmer (it's not a compliment),, but can be unavoidable at times (unlike here). You can use the dereferenced pointer to set the type-size, e.g. `int **arr = calloc(rows, sizeof *arr);` and `arr[i] = calloc(columns, sizeof *a[i]);` Do it that way and you never get your type-size wrong.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Is that different from what I said in my answer? I didn't change the calloc calls because I try to minimize deviations from the original code that don't directly relate to the question.

Comment: How the second writes to a **copy** of ```int **``` provided by main?

Comment: @GulshanMishra When you call a function in C, the function recieves _copies_ of the function parameters. If you pass an `int` as a parameter, the function receives a copy of that `int`. Any work done in the function on that `int` won't be reflected in the original caller's copy. The situation with your `int **`s is the exact same.